# How to highlight members of Asp Class in MVS10, when class situated in external file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, asp-classic, vbscript, ide

How to get microsoft visual studio 2010 highlight members of VBScript (Classic ASP) Class, when class is situated in an external file and added to script using `#include`?

Is that possible?

Here is a code Example:

```
<%@language="VBScript" %>
<% 
    ' Scripted by AB

    Option Explicit 

    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Session.CodePage = 65001

    Class MyClass1

        Function Test()
            Test = "MyClass1 function test"
        End Function    

    End Class

    Dim obj : Set obj = New MyClass1

    obj. ' <--- Show Test 

%>
<!-- #include virtual='/app_code/core/inc_class_test2.asp' -->
<%   

    Dim obj2 : Set obj2 = New MyClass2 ' from inc_class_test2.asp 

    obj2. ' <--- Show nothing

%>
```

In my projects a lot of "chubby" classes and I began to forget what methods there are. Has anyone encountered this problem and knows of an elegant solution?